# jquery appending button error!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just a quick little thing I'm obviously doing wrong:

```
theDiv.append('<input type="button" id='+id+ 'value='+value+'></input>');
```

Where id and value are variables that I assign to as strings. Why wouldn't this work? What's the quick work-around?

thanks.

Comment: Need a little more information to help. You're trying to append an empty string to a div element?

Comment: arg no, I just didnt format it... ill edit. it says: 
'<input type="button" id='+id+ 'value='+value+'></input>'. Stackoverflow took my html literally! lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between the id and the `value` attribute:

```
 // --------------------------------------v
.append('<input type="button" id="'+id+ '" value="'+value+'">');
```

I also added double quotes around the attribute values, and removed the closing `</input>` tag.

This results in:

```
<input type="button" id="id" value="value">
```

...given "id" as the value of `id`, and "value" as the value of `value`.

The way you had it, the value of the `id` attribute, and the `value` attribute itself were merged, so if the value of `id` was "id", it would look like:

```
<input type="button" id=idvalue=value>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does work. You are just missing your quotation marks around the attributes:

```
theDiv.append('<input type="button" id="'+id+ '" value="'+value+'" />');
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/LqvyQ/

Answer (score 1):

If I have id = 1 and value = 15 then this is what makes it to the page

```
<input type="button" id=1value=15></input>
```

When you should really have

```
<input type="button" id="1" value="15"></input>
```